# Is soybean oil the most hazardous oil?

Tags: nutrition, public-health

The 2 minute video by Dr Berg  states that soya oil is the most hazardous oil and most hazardous soya product.
Does this also apy to raw soya oil in canned tun?

https://www.google.com/search?q=Dr+berg+soy+oil&oq=Dr+berg+soy+oil&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0i22i30.3686j0j4&client=ms-android-huawei-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#

Comment: Where does it say it's the "most hazardous"? Please add a quote.

Comment: Adding a link to a google search does not fix this question. There is no such claim here.

Comment: Your edit has invalidated the existing answer. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

[The paper that the article references](https://academic.oup.com/endo/article/161/2/bqz044/5698148) describes how gene expression in the hypothalamus is different in mice fed different diets, and found of the few that were tested, more genes were significantly different between those containing unsaturated soya oil than those containing saturated coconut oil or low fat diets.

This is an interesting finding, showing a link between diet and gene expression in the brain.  It does not say the soya oil is the most hazardous oil, for reasons that could be summarised as:

- We do not know the effect of the changes observed

  - They found that the genes that were different between coconut and soya oil were linked to neuroendocrine, neurochemical, signaling, and gene regulation pathways, but we do not know what effect these changes had on the organism
- This only really compares these 2 oils

  - Coconut oil is saturated, soya is unsaturated.  This is a significant chemical difference, and would be expected to have an effect.  There are many other unsaturated oils, and we do not have any data (AFAIK) on the effect of these on hypothalamic gene expression.  Olive oil has lots of unsaturated oils, and that is generally considered good for you.
- This only talks about a tiny part of the body

  - While the hypothalamus is a crucial part of our endocrine system, it is a small part of the bodies lipid processing system, and gene expression here cannot be extrapolated to make statements about the wider health effects of food
- This is in mice

  - Mice are a great laboratory model, being small, easy to house and kind of close to us evolutionarily.  However they are not just little people, and expanding knowledge for them to us is a difficult business.  In particular they have evolved to deal with a very different diet, and so would be expected to process lipids differently